# Cannot connect to database using GUI

Tags: database, postgresql, ssh, command-line, terminal

Hello its my first time using GUI software for postgres. 
I want to know how to connect to my database using pdAdmin or any other software.

I usually connect using command line

1. I use ssh @example.a.x
2. I insert my password.
3. I use psql -h webdb to connect to postgres
4. I enter my database password. 
   Inside Postgres

How can I connect using a GUI software? or would i be able to?

Comment: Which "GUI software" are you talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Click 'Add a connection to a server' button at the top left.
2. In the dialog box that appears, fill in the details

   2.1 Name: Anything relevant to your database

   2.2 Host: Address of your database (localhost, any other IP address)

   2.3 Port: The port in which database is running on (5432 default)

   2.4 Username: Username you use to log in to the database

   2.4 Password: Password to log in to the database

   Leave other options as they are. You can additionally configure colors.
3. Click on to View -> Tick Object browser (CTRL + ALT + O) will work too
4. There you'll see your recently added server. Connect to it.

Comment: Hi thank you for the comment. Which software are you using? This method doesn't work since I need to run   psql -h webdb after ssh.

Comment: i use pgadmin. well i've never connected to postgre like that but there might be an IP address or something for webdb?

Comment: @Satsuki, you need to setup an ssh-tunnel first. Probably this article will help: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssh-tunnels.html